# Spring batch paginated reader and Exception handling

Tags: spring-boot, exception, pagination, spring-batch

We created a custom item reader which extends `AbstractPaginatedDataItemReader`. Spring-batch allows to manage which exception stops or not a job (skipped exceptions).

In "classic" spring-batch readers, the `doRead` method throws any `Exception`. That means, if a skipped exception is thrown during the read, the item is skipped and the job continues running.

But in paginated readers, the `doPageRead` method, used to retrieve next data page, doesn't throw any exception:

```
protected abstract Iterator<T> doPageRead();
```

The `doPageRead` method is called by the `doRead` one:

```
protected T doRead() throws Exception {

    synchronized (lock) {
        if(results == null || !results.hasNext()) {

            results = doPageRead();

            page ++;

            if(results == null || !results.hasNext()) {
                return null;
            }
        }


        if(results.hasNext()) {
            return results.next();
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

As `doPageRead` method doesn't declare any thrown exception, that means a configured skipped exception can only be a `RuntimeException`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Spring Batch reader is eventually an `ItemReader` irrespective of it being a paging reader or a non - paging reader. Which eventually means that it will hand over single - single items to processor and `read()` method contract is all that matters.

Paging readers simply have an optimization about how they actually read an item but no different than than a regular non - paging reader.

So in my opinion, your look out for `doReadPage()` method seems unnecessary, what matters is `read()` method contract.

If you are facing any issue ( and that is not clear from your question ) , do let me know.